# Vb.NET MS Access SQL UPDATE Syntax Issue

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have been hammering away at this for hours but haven't gotten it right so I decided to post.

My Vb.NET app has a 2 Jpgs on the harddrive. One is `LowRes` and the other is `HighRes`. I want to save both pictures in the same record in a Microsoft Access 2007 database via `INSERT`, which works fine, and then `UPDATE` to add the second one. The `UPDATE` is not working.

I pieced together a bunch of code I found online for the `INSERT` code (learning as I go) and eventually figured something out that actually worked. However, trying to tweak the function to do a UPDATE to add the second picture is proving difficult. I suspect its something to do with me specifying parameters wrong?

The database has 1 table `Records` with 3 columns `RecordID` (which is Text, and a autonumber primary key which is pulled from `Form1.Tb_RecordID.Text`), `HighRes` (which is OLE) and `LowRes` (Which is also OLE). The database is named `Database.accdb`.

I call the subroutine with:

```
Save_To_Database("LowProfile.jpg", "LowRes")
```

if I want it to `INSERT` an OLE image in the "LowRes" column. I then call

```
Update_To_Database("HighProfile.jpg", "HighRes")
```

to update the record with the `HighRes` picture. I eventually want to consolidate these functions one to one and use ByVals to determine if it should Update or Insert.

This works fine:

```
Sub Save_To_Database(ByVal Filename As String, ByVal Res As String)

    Dim cnString As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database.accdb"
    Dim theQuery As String = "INSERT INTO Records([RecordID],[" & Res & "]) values (" & Form1.Tb_RecordID.Text & ", @Img)"

    Try
        Dim fs As FileStream
        fs = New FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim picByte As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
        fs.Read(picByte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))
        fs.Close()
        Dim CN As New OleDbConnection(cnString)
        CN.Open()
        Dim imgParam As New OleDbParameter()
        imgParam.OleDbType = OleDbType.Binary
        imgParam.ParameterName = "Img"
        imgParam.Value = picByte
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(theQuery, CN)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(imgParam)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Image successfully saved.")
        cmd.Dispose()
        CN.Close()
        CN.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

However, my `UPDATE` code fails with a syntax error on the SQL statement:

```
Sub Update_To_Database(ByVal Filename As String, ByVal Res As String)

    Dim cnString As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database.accdb"
    Dim theQuery As String = "UPDATE Records SET ([" & Res & "]) values (@Img) WHERE RecordID =" & Form1.Tb_RecordID.Text

    MsgBox(theQuery)

    Try
        Dim fs As FileStream
        fs = New FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim picByte As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
        fs.Read(picByte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))
        fs.Close()
        Dim CN As New OleDbConnection(cnString)
        CN.Open()
        Dim imgParam As New OleDbParameter()
        imgParam.OleDbType = OleDbType.Binary
        imgParam.ParameterName = "Img"
        imgParam.Value = picByte
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(theQuery, CN)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(imgParam)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Image successfully saved.")
        cmd.Dispose()
        CN.Close()
        CN.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Anyone see the problem? Or a way to improve the code?

Comment: Use something like this `UPDATE Records SET ([" & Res & "])  = @Img WHERE`

Comment: I found this thread: Tinyurl.com/hkjwtwz and really like how he structued his SQL and even how it checks to see if the record exsists. Im trying to modify it to do something like that but I dont know what to do with imgParam or fs.

Comment: Also Abhay. It still is throwing a syntax error. I did a Msgbox to see the string and it says: "UPDATE Records SET ([HighRes]) = @img WHERE RecordID =1" if that helps.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Try taking out the brackets around [HighRes]:.  `UPDATE Records SET [HighRes] = @Img ....`

Answer (score 0):

Your original problem is the fact that you tried to write an update statement using the syntax of an insert statement. An easy fix would be simply to change the update statement to the correct syntax.

However,  there are a number of things in your code that could be and should be changed, so I wrote an example based on your code that still can be improved further:

```
Sub Save_To_Database(ByVal Filename As String, ByVal RecordId As String, ByVal IsHighResolution As Boolean, ByVal IsNew As Boolean)

    Dim theQuery As String
    Dim cnString As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database.accdb"

    If IsNew Then
        theQuery = "INSERT INTO Records([RecordID],[" & IIf(IsHighResolution, "HighRes", "LowRes") & "]) values (@RecordId, @Img)"
    Else
        theQuery = "UPDATE Records SET " & IIf(IsHighResolution, "HighRes", "LowRes") & " = @Img WHERE RecordID = @RecordId"
    End If

    Try
        Using fs As New FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Dim picByte As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
            fs.Read(picByte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))
            Using CN As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)

                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(theQuery, CN)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Img", OleDbType.Binary).Value = picByte
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = RecordId

                CN.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Image successfully saved.")
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Points of interest:

1. Insert and update is now handled by the same method, only difference is a Boolean parameter that specifies if this is a new record or an existing one.
2. Queries are now safe from sql injection. The only concatenation here is the column name that you can't parameterize in sql, but it is decided inside the sub itself. When you use the sub, you only pass a boolean value indicating of this is a high resolution image.
3. The Using block is recommended to use whenever you are using anything that implements the IDisposable interface. This ensures the correct closer and disposal even in a case of an exception being thrown.
4. Parameters code simplified.

Comment: You beat me to a few advancements I thought of such as including those byVals and the If statement for the query as well as setting Record ID as a parameter. I never know about IIF and will make a note of it. Also it looks a lot better. Still haven't got the hang of Using yet. Ill test this out tomorrow. Next project is figure out how to read this and populate the appropriate pictureboxes.

Comment: Ok, so i tried it and it it throws an error on the INSERT statement, but says the UPDATE statement was successful, even though no records/information are written to the database. It successfully updated nothing. I gives the error: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." I tried my old concatenate INSERT statement and it works fine, which makes me think the @RecordId parameter is having issues. I CInt the RecordID when I call the sub, I changed the ByVal to integer, and it still is giving the error. I'm missing something.

Comment: Also RecordID is created by a autonumber sequence and is read from a disabled and readonly field, I doubt it could/would be vulnerable to any type of SQL Injection....but still.

Comment: Can you post your table's Create statement?

Comment: The table is pre-created in Access. Both fields are OLE fields, I checked.

Comment: also on: cmd.Parameters.Add("Img", OleDbType.Binary).Value = picByte and cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = RecordId...why does RecordId say @RecordId while Img doesnt have the @?

Comment: A mistake. Img should also have the `@` sign.